# Let R be a commutative ring, and let P be a prime ideal of R. Suppose that P has no nontrivial zero divisors in it. Show that R is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let R be a commutative ring, and let P be a prime ideal of R. Suppose that P has no nontrivial zero divisors in it. Show that R is an integral domain.

My proof:

Take $r,s,a \in R$ with $ar = as$, and $p \in P$. Then

\begin{align*}
par &= pas\\
a p r &= a p s && \text{R is commutative}
\end{align*}
and since $P$ is an ideal of $R$, then $pr, ps \in P$.
Since $P$ is an integral domain, then $a p r = a p s \implies p r = p s$, so $r = s$.

I'm not using the fact that $P$ is a prime ideal which leads me to believe that I messed up a step.

Comment: An ideal is not a ring, hence it is meaningless to say P is an integral domain.

Comment: @Bernard maybe you should recheck the definition of an ideal. It is subring, therefore a ring.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in commutative algebra, a subring has a unit element, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @Bernard, well, ok, you might want to insist on unit, but being integral domain is perfectly well defined for non-unital rings, thus for ideals.

Comment: According to Jacobson and Bourbaki, a ring has a unit element, otherwise it's a rng (Jacobson) or a pseudo-ring (Bourbaki).

Comment: I changed the title to the actual question. My book assumes that rings need a unit element. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: In fact, it does not require identity to solve this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $ab=0$, then from $0\in P$ we get $a\in P$ or $b\in P$. Since $P$ doesn't contain non-zero zero-divisors we get $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Thanks this is a nice proof. I was trying to show that elements are cancelable to show that it was an integral domain.

Comment: If $a\in P$ or $b\in P,$ how do we conclude that $a=0$ or $b=0?$ If $a\in P,$ does it mean that $a$ is a zero divisor **in $P$**?

Comment: @Idonknow Yes, this means that $a$ is a zero-divisor in $P$.

Comment: @user26857 my definition of zero divisor is as follows: $a$ is a zero divisor in $P$ if there exists a nonzero element $b$ in $P$ such that $ab=0$ or $ba=0$. In the proof above, you have shown that if $ab=0$, then either $a\in P$ or $b\in P$. However, if $a\in P$, how do we we know that $b\in P$ as well?

Comment: @Idonknow Sorry, but when I posted this answer I wasn't aware of your definition of zero-divisors in $P$. Starting from here you could ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In your proof, you say that $apr=aps\Rightarrow pr=ps$ "because $P$ is an integral domain."

Even if I do not like the fact of using domains with no unit, you can of course do it. But to say that $apr=aps$ implies $pr=ps$, you implicitly write $a(pr-ps)=0$ and assume that $a\not=0$ (that you did not write but implicitly you assume this) and want to deduce that $pr=ps$. This is true in an integral domain, which is your assumption on $P$, but the element $a$ does not belong to $P$. This is the problem in your proof.

For a correct (and simple) proof, see the answer of user26857.