# $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that every prime ideal contains no non-zero zero divisor , then is $R$ an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that every prime ideal contains no non-zero zero divisor (i.e. if $P$ is a prime ideal and $x,y \in P$ with $xy=0$ then either $x=0$ , or $y=0$). Then is $R$ an integral domain ? (I want every prime ideal $P$ to contain no non-zero divisor as a ring in it's own right, not that $P$ contains no non-zero divisor of $R$.)

This question is related to [Let R be a commutative ring, and let P be a prime ideal of R. Suppose that P has no nontrivial zero divisors in it. Show that R is an integral domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564764/let-r-be-a-commutative-ring-and-let-p-be-a-prime-ideal-of-r-suppose-that-p-has), but is not exactly same.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Let $x$ a zero divisor. Then, it is not invertible. Therefore, it is contained in a maximal ideal...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : I think you are might be heading in the same wrong direction due ( perhaps ) to lack of clarification in the question body ? ( although I mentioned it clearly in parenthesis ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if $R=K\times K$ with $K$ a field? There are only two prime ideals $K\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times K$, and for both we have $x,y\in P$ with $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$.