# If P is a prime ideal of a ring R and P contains no non-zero zero divisors, then R is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here, $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. I realize there are many proofs of this online, but all of them seem to assume a definition of zero divisors that Dummit and Foote does not. Here is what the definition is in Dummit and Foote:

If $a \in P$ and $b \in P$, then $ab = 0$ implies either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. The crucial assumption here is that both $a,b \in P$. So the solution for this problem typically goes something like this:

Let $P$ be a prime ideal, and suppose we have $a,b \in R$ such that $ab = 0$. But since $P$ is an ideal, $ab \in P$, and since $P$ is prime, this implies that either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. Without loss of generality, assume $a \in P$. If $a = 0$, we are done, so suppose $a \neq 0$. **Then since $P$ has no zero divisors, this implies $b = 0$.**

This last sentence is my main issue. It seems to imply that $b \in P$, which we are not given at all. So how would one prove this? I also tried using the fact that $R/P$ is an integral domain, but I got stuck at the same place.

Comment: Question is similar [to this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1664005/29335) except in that one they are saying "$a,b\in P$ and $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$." Rather than $a,b\in R$.  It's clearly true that if any nonzero pair of zero divisors exists in a ring, then every prime ideal must contain one of those zero divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mean "$P$ contains no (nonzero) zero divisors" or else the hypothesis would never hold: $0$ is always in $P$.

So you are starting with "suppose $a,b\in R$, both are nonzero, and $ab=0$."  This begins a proof by contradiction.

So here is where things can be improved:

> Without loss of generality, assume $a \in P$. If $a = 0$, we are done, so suppose $a \neq 0$. **Then since $P$ has no zero divisors, this implies $b = 0$.**

can be more like either

> Without loss of generality, assume $a \in P$.  By Assumption $P$ contains no zero divisors, so $ab=0$ implies $b=0$. But this contradicts the earlier assumption that $b\neq 0$.

or

> Without loss of generality, assume $a \in P$.  But $b\neq 0$ witnesses that $a$ is a zero divisor of $R$. But this contradicts the earlier assumption that $P$ contains no zero divisors.

Comment: Both of your suggestions rely on the assumption that $b \in P$. $P$ contains no zero divisors if $ab = 0$ implies $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, but it requires that both $a,b \in P$.

Comment: @Alex No, I read "$P$ has no zero divisors" to mean "$P$ contains no zero divisors of $R$."  The version requiring both $a,b\in P$ doesn't seem very natural to me, and the disproof of the statement is covered by the link I put in the comments above.

Comment: Like in $R=F\times F$ for a field $F$: the ideal $I=\{0\}\times F$ is prime and does not contain a pair of nonzer elements that annihilate each other (of course, it is made up entirely of zero divisors of $R$ along with $0$.)